# Where can I edit requested scopes for the Google OAuth2 consent screen?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We used to be able to edit the granted scopes in the Google OAuth 2 consent screen per images in this link:

https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/d5ucukMP10w

[image]

Where did the option to choose which scopes are being granted go?

It's not in the GCP OAuth Consent Screen / Credentials area.

Comment: The scopes that appear in the consent screen come from your code. You send them with the request for authorization. The image in your picture just shows what scopes you are declaring for verification.    Not sure i understand the question.

Comment: Dude, you hit the nail on the head. My bad, it's a config for passport. THUNDERCATS HO!